# if it is possible to capture events in elasticache (redis) such as deletion of registers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, elastic-cache

I want to know if there is way to capture when a register is deleted from redis on AWS Elasticache. I searched that there is a way of send notification when a cluster of redis is deleted but I dont want that. Someone knows ?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/ElastiCacheSNS.html

Comment: what do you mean by register ? do you mean "key" ?

Comment: If you are looking to receive an event when a redis key is deleted (or expired) take a look at Redis keyspace notifications https://redis.io/topics/notifications

Comment: Yeah , I mean register as a key-value. Thanks  @namizaru for your answer, I'm going to check out.